# T-SQL CONVERT fails with providing ISO formatted string + style

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error I didn't expect to see when using `CONVERT` with an ISO formatted string, but only when specifying a style code (I've tried a few, and they all throw the error).

For example, this succeeds and returns the datetime in my local format:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2020-01-15T00:00:00')
```

But this fails with an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '2020-01-15T00:00:00', 103)
```

I feel I must be missing something very basic here. Can anyone explain?

Comment: `103` is the `dd/mm/yyyy` format, so an error is expected. Why do you specify `103` when it's clearly wrong? You don't need to specify a format with `ISO8601` strings

Comment: *"I feel I must be missing something very basic here"* You are, a reread of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles). Style 103 is clearly marked as `dd/MM/yyyy`. Your value is *not* `dd/MM/yyyy` it 's `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`; a completely different format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`103` *forces* the format for `convert()`.

Otherwise, `convert()` is somewhat flexible on the format you can provide.  *It does not just use the default format.*

Your format, in fact, is the standard format for date/time values.  And so it recognizes that regardless of the local settings.  Similarly, a string `YYYYMMDD` is always recognized as a valid date, regardless of the local settings.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood how this function worked. I thought the style was to override the output, not specify the format of the input. Many thanks.

Comment: @Calan . . . That's funny.  The style is used for the result when converting to a string.  So you are not 100% misunderstanding it; only 50%.